# bat file kill itself?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

We currently have a scheduled task on a server, it runs a bat file which copies files from one machine to another.  The file looks like:

```
@echo off

net use t: \\xxxxx\copy password /user:xxx\xyz /persistent:yes
move t:\*.txt  C:\testfiles

net use t: /delete

taskkill /f /fi "USERNAME eq xyz" /im conhost.exe 

exit
```

When the task runs I noticed in task manager cmd.exe and conhost.ext are started, I wanted to stop them once the task is done.  Killing the conhost.ext manually seems to kill them both.  The above bat file runs fine but the conhost.exe is not killed, I wasn't sure if it can kill itself?  As running that line in another bat file works.  As currently once the task is done those two are still showing up in task manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`conhost.exe` is [executed automatically](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/4996/what-is-conhost.exe-and-why-is-it-running/) for each console application and exits automatically when the application exits, you don't have to kill it explicitly. So just kill `cmd.exe`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to get the cmd.exe own process so you'll kill only the current instance of cmd.exe . You can use for example [getCmdPID.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/getCmdPID.bat):

```
@echo off
call getCmdPid.bat 
taskkill /pid %errorlevel%
pause
```